# C# - multiple Prod configurations

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a Production program that uses two distinct configurations.  They are called using a parameter (eg exec Myprog.exe parm=Conf1 and exec Myprog.exe parm=Conf2)

Is it possible to have sections within the configuration file that will use the configuration variables based on the configuration.  I have seen examples where you can do this in the build (eg for dev vs prod), but not for two different prod releases.

I know that I can call them from two different directories and have a different config file in each directory, but that is messy.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do it that way you can add another build for Conf1 and Conf2, you aren't just limited to debug and release configurations

You can find a good tutorial on the specifics [here](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com.au/2009/03/web-deployment-webconfig-transformation_23.html) and explanations of some of the tranforms [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28VS.100%29.aspx)

The basic steps are

1. Create the configurations
2. Add transforms for the configurations
3. Write transforms to do the actual modification for different
   releases
4. Generate the transform (will be done on deploy depending on how you
   are doing things)
5. Profit

EDIT: there is also another good tutorial on the [offical ASP.net site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/Deployment-to-a-Hosting-Provider-Web-Config-File-Transformations-3-of-12)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Daniel.  However, what I'm trying to do is determine the configuration at runtime - not build / deploy time, based on a parameter.  So if parameter is 'conf1', I pick 1 set of configuration options, and another set for parameter 'conf2'.

I can duplicate all the variables and use Var1_conf1, Var1_conf2, etc, but i was hoping to be able to replace the configuration file at runtime, or alternatively set up configuration groups in a single configuration file.

Comment: why are you changing this at runtime, do you frequently change the "context" of a server? sounds like maybe you might need to alter your process, need a little more information about exactly why you are doing this